# How do I disable LED lights on Dell Latitude D620? (power, hard drive, battery, wifi)

Tags: lubuntu, dell, power-management, brightness, 18.10

(Summary: How do I disable lights on the laptop hinge showing power, WiFi, etc. activity?)

On the Dell Latitude D620 laptop hinge, below and next to the screen, above the keyboard, on the right hand side are four green lights, which I understand to represent power, hard disk activity, battery charging activity, and WiFi activity.

[image: Activity/Status LEDs on hinge of Dell Latitude D620]

The power and WiFi lights remain lit constantly. The WiFi light turns off if the WiFi switch on the left of the laptop is switched off, and turns back on when switched back on. (Of course, so does the WiFi connection.)

The problem is that the power and WiFi lights remain on constantly, and the WiFi light is particularly bright. After sunset it becomes a nuisance due to its excessive brightness, and there's no particular need for me to be told every moment that my laptop's power and WiFi are working. For these reasons I wish to disable these lights via Lubuntu 18.10; I have been told Linux gives the user greater control over his computer, and I wish to take advantage of this potential. How do I do so?

(In the meantime I have been physically blocking the lights with small objects, but I am hoping there is a more elegant solution as I do not wish to put tape adhesive residue + sticky-note cutout on this hinge.

Comment: Did you check your BIOS for settings? Because this tends to be hardware related.

Comment: I agree with @Rinzwind; typically these kinds of things cannot be controlled by the OS.

Comment: Your question has an answer here:https://askubuntu.com/questions/587078/is-it-possible-to-disable-a-notebooks-leds-temporarily-hdd-power-charging

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to disable a notebook's LEDs temporarily? (HDD, Power, Charging)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587078/is-it-possible-to-disable-a-notebooks-leds-temporarily-hdd-power-charging)